# Return specific dates, months from any year using python date time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

**To clarify**, I actually need to return multiple months, for example October through December.

I have a dataframe with 10000s of rows where my index is a time_stamp. I want to get the values that fall between certain months for all of the years in the dataframe.

I've tried this: `print(df.loc['%Y-10-01':'%Y-12-31'])` along with `YYYY`, `****`, `%y` but I can't figure out how to return the date time objects that match for any year.

The dataframe `df` looks something like this:

```
2015-07-13  0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    17.018001   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
2017-07-27  0.000000    1.016000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
2017-07-03  1.778000    12.700000   3.048000    7.874000    5.588000    2.540000    28.448001   26.670000   58.420003   19.812001   12.446000
```

Comment: `df.iloc[df.index.month == 7]` should be enough.

Comment: I updated my question because I need more than just one month in the output.

Comment: Added my answer...  take a look and see if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular problem, it would seem like an `isin` check on a range of months would be the simplest:

```
df.iloc[df.index.month.isin(np.r_[10:13])]
```

`np.r_` makes it convenient to specify intermittent ranges. For example, if you want Jan-Feb, April, and Oct-Dec, use:

```
i = np.r_[1:3, 4, 10:13]

i
array([ 1,  2,  4, 10, 11, 12])
```

Comment: Thank you! Your are so helpful @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ